# Get count of unique strings from range in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I've below function which gives unique cells but I want to find unique strings in all cells of given range.

Code:

```
Public Function CountUnique(rng As Range) As Integer
Dim dict As Dictionary
Dim cell As Range
Set dict = New Dictionary
For Each cell In rng.Cells
     If Not dict.Exists(cell.Value) Then
        dict.Add cell.Value, 0
    End If
Next
CountUnique = dict.Count
End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

```
Sub Test_CountUnique_UDF()
MsgBox CountUnique(Range("B1:B4"))
End Sub

Public Function CountUnique(rng As Range) As Integer
Dim e, dict As Dictionary, cell As Range

Set dict = New Dictionary

For Each cell In rng.Cells
    For Each e In Split(cell, ", ")
        If Not dict.Exists(e) Then dict.Add e, 0
    Next e
Next cell

CountUnique = dict.Count
End Function
```

Another variation (late binding)

```
Sub Test_CountUniq_UDF()
MsgBox CountUniq(Range("B1:B4"), ",")
End Sub

Function CountUniq(rng As Range, delim As String) As Long
Dim e       As Variant
Dim s       As Variant

With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    .CompareMode = 1
    For Each e In rng.Value
        If Trim$(e) <> "" Then
            For Each s In Split(e, delim)
                If Trim$(s) <> "" Then .item(Trim$(s)) = Empty
            Next s
        End If
    Next e
    CountUniq = .Count
End With
End Function
```

Comment: But when cell has data like `test5,test2`, it treats as 1 string.